# Why is PHP loop causing a forbidden page after 250 loops?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

RESOLVED: The issue was sort of related to max_input_vars. The server I use has a security framework called "Suhosin". There were two values that function very similarly to max_input_vars that were set to 1,000. The values were "suhosin.post.max_vars" and "suhosin.request.max_vars". I has those set to 5,000 and everything works great now!

### ---------------

---

I've currently got a page that uses PHP to display a bunch of images with print ordering options beneath them, and 'while' loops until every one is displayed. It works fine, every image is displayed. The user is meant to pick what they want to print, then click "Submit". This sends the form via the page submit.php. Submit.php generates a list of what they picked by storing the data in an array. That array is then imploded and emailed to an address as text. Four array entries are submitted for every image. The data is sent using $_POST

Now, this functions perfectly if less than 250 images are selected on the first page. If 250 or more are selected, the submit.php page turns into a Forbidden error page and no email is sent.

I assumed it was because the server is treating it as an infinite loop or maybe something to do with it handling so many array entries. I really need this fixed. Does anyone know any solutions?

EDIT - Here is the loop on submit.php. I know it's probably not the best code, I'm still learning.

EDIT 2 - I tried changing max_input_vars to 5000 and it didn't work. I added it to my PHP.ini file, the line wasn't there previously. I can't reboot server as it's shared hosting. Any other ideas?

EDIT 3 - Okay, some great progress has been made. I no longer get a Forbidden page, however the email does not send when the loop is higher than 250. It still sends successfully at < 250.

```
$imgcount = $_SESSION['imgcount'];
$usercode = $_SESSION['usercode'];

// echo $imgcount . "<br><br>";
$extramessage = $_POST["message"];

$currentcount = 1;


$completeorder = array();

    while ($currentcount <= $imgcount) {
        $x = $_POST["print_amount_" . $currentcount . ""];
        // echo "<b><u>Image " . $currentcount . "</u></b><br>";
        // echo $x[0] . ", " . $x[1] . ", " . $x[2] . ", " . $x[3] . ", " . "<br><br>";
        $y = (string) "Image " . $currentcount . " - " . $x[0] . ", " . $x[1] . ", " . $x[2] . ", " . $x[3] . "
        ";
        // echo $y;
        $completeorder[] = $y;
        // echo $completeorder . "<br><br>";


        $currentcount = $currentcount + 1;
    };

$completeorder = implode( "\n", $completeorder );
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Too Many Post Data variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13617339/too-many-post-data-variables) *"There is a PHP setting called max_input_vars that defaults to 1000."*

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: could you post the code of your php loop ?

Comment: I tried adding the max_input_vars line to my php.ini as it wasn't there and setting it to 5000 and it didn't work. I'm adding the code to my original post now.

Comment: @JacinTattersall You may need to restart your server after editing the config file. It's just too much of a coincidence, 249 * 4 + some other fields <= 1000, 250 * 4 + some other fields > 1000.

Comment: @Stijn My server is a shared hosting server, I don't have the ability to restart it unfortunately.

Comment: It shows Forbidden or error 500 Normally when you have the server as production, try to switch it to development, or at the beginning of your code:
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
To view the actual errors, that will help you debug better

Comment: @aleation Tried adding that line to the start of submit.php, however it still yields the same Forbidden page.

Comment: sorry my bad, that only works with server errors, not with forbidden pages, anyway maybe it is the 1000 limit. as @Stijn said you need to restart the server, even if it's a shared hosting normally they should have an option to apply the config changes through the Panel, or through the tech support if not. Still, I would recommend you to have a local environment to test this kind of things, where you have total control, setting up a WAMP/LAMP/MAMP is really quick and easy

Comment: @aleation - I contacted my hosting company's live support and they restarted the server for me. It didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Btw, You shouldn't have a semi-colon after the closing curly brace of the while loop

Comment: Could you edit your question and show us how would $_POST["print_amount_1"] looks like ? also $extramessage is a string or is an array of messages? I'm gonna try to reproduce the error

Comment: Also just remembered, when you can't change your config file, the ini_set() is used to override the config file's value, in this case ini_set('max_input_vars', 5000) at the beginning of the script would have worked without changing the config file or restarting the server

Comment: @aleation - $extramessage is just one string from a message box on the previous page. What do you mean about how $_POST["print_amount_1"] would look? print_amount_1 is an array that contains four variables. Each variable is just a 1 or 2 digit number depending on what the user enters on the previous page.

Comment: In fact I just tried to do the same way and I'm hitting the Input variables exceeded 1000 error. max_input_vars can't be changed with ini_set so you will have to check if it's actually changed, create a php script with this line of code: phpinfo(); and run it, look for the max_input_var value and see if it's over 1000. If it isn't changed insist on the tech, or add this to your .htaccess: php_value max_input_vars 3000
Anyway the code seems to work, it's more about configurations your problem

Comment: @JacinTattersall - If you have a solution, please post it as an answer below and mark it as accepted, rather than editing it into the question. This will make it easier to find for people in the future who have a similar question, and will also prevent it showing up in the 'unanswered questions' list.

Comment: Okay, will do. Sorry this is my first time using the site, didn't realise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED: The issue was sort of related to max_input_vars. The server I use has a security framework called "Suhosin". There were two values that function very similarly to max_input_vars that were set to 1,000. The values were "suhosin.post.max_vars" and "suhosin.request.max_vars". I have now got those set to 5,000 and everything works great now!

max_input_vars, suhosin.post.max_vars and suhosin.request.max_vars all default to 1000. To check what they are set as, execute the following:

phpinfo();

Then CTRL + F and look-up those settings to see what they're set at. You might not have any "suhosin" settings in yours. If simply changing max_input_vars doesn't do the trick, CTRL + F for "1000" and see if anything that has a value of 1000 is related to "post" or "vars" or anything that would limit your maximum variables.

Answer (score 0):

You are storen a lot of variables, maybe you reach the `memory_limit` of your php.ini settings.

try this with some debug outputs like this:

```
echo "Memory: ".memory_get_usage(true) . " - PEAK: ".memory_get_peak_usage(true) . " MAX: ".ini_get("memory_limit");
```

But realy strange is that you get an forbidden page ...
Even if reach some limits of php or of the ini_settings you normaly get an `Error 500 Internal Server Error` of an visible output to your browser (only if `display_errors` enabled).

So it also could be, that your webserver has some kind of restriction what is answered with an forbidden page.

Comment: Already tried increasing the memory_limit but it didn't fix the issue. I'm in a live support chat with my hosting company right now and the guy says he has identified the reason for the problem but needs to see if he can fix it. Must be a server setting and not a code issue.